# How to create an array where numbers increase by 3?

Tags: python

I want to create an array of shape (280,). It will start from 3 and add 3 each time:

```
array = [3,6,9,12,15...n+3]
```

How would I do this in Python?

Comment: `list(range(3, n+4, 3))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `range` in python:

```
>>> length = 5
>>> n = 3
>>> l1 = list(range(n,n*(length+1),n)) #start, stop, step
>>> l1
[3, 6, 9, 12, 15]
```

See more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) in docs.

Answer (score 1):

```
array = [i for i in range(3,3*281,3)] # this gets to 280 values in the list
```

To get to 280 values, you need to multiple 281 by the step you want, since the upper value is exclusive.

So this will give you a list from 3 - 840, stepping by 3 between each value.

Of course, as per the other answer, it could also be:

```
array = list(range(3, 3*281, 3))
```

Comment: OP wants the length to be 280, this ends at 280.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `range(start, stop, step)`:

stop is exclusive, so in your case:

```
step = 3
l = list(range(3, 281*step, step))
len(l) # resuls in 280
```

Comment: OP wants the length to be 280, this ends at 280.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. This ends in 280. I'm looking to have 280 elements in the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you explicitly need an array, this can also be done quite easily with `numpy`

```py
import numpy as np

desired_length = 280
stepsize = 3

x = np.arange(desired_length*stepsize, step=stepsize)
```